# Approximate modified Bessel Integral as x goes to infinty

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I'm asked to show that as $x \to \infty$ the modified Bessel function $$
I_n(x) :=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_o^\pi e^{x \cos \theta} \cos n \theta \ d\theta \sim \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}.
$$

I am not quite sure how to go about this. I have tried integration by parts without much success as terms all seem to go to zero. Any suggestions as to a method of approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use Bessel differential equation? It makes the asymptotics obvious

Comment: Unfortunately the idea of the exercise is asymptotic evaluation of integrals. It would be much easier if i could use the Differential equation.

Comment: I see. I'll try to do something directly. Normally, I would attempt to change the variable under the integral in a way that brings $x$ out, then take the limit

Comment: If you're familiar with the Laplace method, the proof is straightforward. The quantity $\cos \theta$ takes its maximum on $[0,\pi]$ at $\theta = 0$, and near there $\cos \theta \approx 1 - \theta^2/2$, so $$\int_0^\pi e^{x\cos\theta} \cos{n\theta}\,d\theta \sim \int_0^\infty e^{x(1-\theta^2/2)} \cos 0 \,d\theta = e^x \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}$$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to derive the asymptotics from the integral itself.

First, we rewrite the exponent, using double angle formulas:

$$\cos \theta=1-2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}$$

And making a substitution: $t= \frac{\theta}{2}$. This gives us the following integral:

$$I_n=\frac{2 e^x}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2 x \sin^2t} \cos (2nt) dt$$

Now naturally, we make a substituion:

$$u=\sin t, \qquad t= \arcsin u$$

I won't specify the exact form of $ \cos (2nt)$ in terms of $u$, I will just denote:

$$f(u)=\cos (2n \arcsin u), \qquad |f(u)| \leq 1$$

Then we can write the integral as:

$$I_n=\frac{2 e^x}{\pi} \int_0^1 e^{-2 x u^2} f(u) \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

Now the final trick will be the substitution:

$$v= \sqrt{x} ~u$$

We get:

> $$I_n=\frac{2 e^x}{\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-2 v^2} f \left( \frac{v}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \frac{dv}{\sqrt{x-v^2}}$$

---

Here's when it gets tricky. I have no idea how to justify the asymptotics, but suppose if for large $x$ we can set the upper limit of the integral to $\infty$, but simultaneously assume $x-v^2 \asymp x$ under the radical sign and also discount $f$ somehow, then we would get:

$$I_n\asymp \frac{2 e^x}{\pi \sqrt{x}} \int_0^\infty e^{-2 v^2} dv=\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}}$$

Which is correct, but the argument I used is not justified in the slightest. So there's still some work to be done.